# Why my BroadcastReceiver stop receiving after a while

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a `IntentService` that does a long work, it takes about 15 minutes to be done. It is a synchronization process to get new data from my server.

When this service starts, I start a activity too, to display the progess.

This activity creates a `BroadcastReceiver`, that intercepts messages sent from the service about the process progress.

If I leave the app doing it job, after a while the SO switch off the screen.

When I switch on the screen again, after about 15 minutes, the service has been already done, but the progress appears to be out of date. The `BroadcastReceiver` has stopped to work, and my `END OF SYNCHRONIZATION` message hasn't been received by the activity.

The problem is that, at this message I start the main activity again to leave the user to use the app again.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Post some code...  I would guess your activity isn't receiving messages because your receivers are unregistered onPause or onDestroy, but it is hard to tell, since there is no code.  I would suggest using serviceBinding and Messengers instead of listening to broadcast receivers and have a stauts message send when your activity binds, to get the most recent status... but again, code would help.

Comment: @AdamW the broadcast is registered and unregistered in onStart and onStop methods.

Comment: You should try it.
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location-updates-android-o/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved with this http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/components/services.html#Foreground .

My service

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    public interface MyCallback {
        void onProgress(int progress);
    }

    public class MyBinder {
        public MyService getService() {
            return MyService.this;
        }
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return new MyBinder();
    }

    public void make(MyCallback callback) {

        Notification n = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Processing")
            .getNotification();

        startForeground(666 /*some ID*/, n);
        try {
            callback.onProgress(0);
            // do the hard sutff and report progress
            callback.onProgress(100); // report 100%
        } finally {
            stopForeground(true);
        }
    }
}
```

My activity

```
public MyActivity extends Activity implements ServiceConnection, MyService.MyCallback {

    @Override
    protected onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // 1 - bind service to this activity
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        this.bindService(i, this, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, final IBinder iBinder) {
        // 2 - when the service was binded, starts the process asynchronous
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                ((MyService.MyBinder) iBinder).getService().make(MyActivity.this);
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgress(int progress) {
        // 3 - when to callback is fired, update the UI progress bar
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // call ProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast Receivers are not made to do long duration work.

The lifetime of a broadcast receiver lasts about 10-15 seconds.

A recommended or typical use of a broadcast receiver is to

- Start a service
- Show a Toast
- Start an Activity

In your case you should start a service from your broadcast Receiver and do all the work in that service.